# Applying AM-GM inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If a,b,c,d are positive integers with a sum of 63, find the maximum value of ab+bc+cd.

How to use the AM-GM inequality here?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the solutions here - https://brilliant.org/problems/a-game-of-abc-and-d/

[image]

Method 2

[image]